# Unicode support in Firefox

Tags: firefox, unicode

Some Unicode characters invisible in Firefox (27.x, Linux). Most are OK, but when it comes down to more exotic signs like miscellaneous characters, it just show a little square.

The range of U+26Dx U+26Ex U+26Fx is totally missing.

Not sure if this is a Linux or Firefox thing.

Comment: Can you show your codes, Unicode texts?

Comment: @Raptor done. Question expanded.

Comment: My question is, how do you show the codes? HTML ? JS ? or CSS `content` ?

Comment: @Raptor. I see. Both HTML and CSS content fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked on Firefox 27.0.1 Mac. My point is, to show Unicode characters, you have to use appropriate method:

When you use in HTML, use NCR form:

```
<p>&#x026D;x</p>
```

When you use in JS, use JavaScript escapes form:

```
$('#js_test').html('\u026Dx');
```

When you use in CSS, use CSS escapes form:

```
#css_test:after {
    content: '\026D x';
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55gH8/1/) and this [Unicode code converter](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/).

Comment: That would work for showing, but what if I want to view from other page (like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols).  Why do some work, and others (from the range above) not?

Comment: Because they are not showing in proper way (the way I show above / in fiddle). NCR form is the most stable form of showing / storing Unicode in HTML

Comment: I'm still not convinced that the problem lies there. Python also has problems showing Unicode in the range U+26Dx and further. But no problem showing Unicode like - ☀☁☂䑕☔.

Comment: I see square block. Oops.